# Problem in making one to one relation in django

Tags: python, django, database, model

I am creating a website where admin will have the right to register the clinic/patient and fill his complete details wile registration

Below is my code

**model.py**

```
import django
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Registered_user(AbstractUser):
   is_clinic = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_patient = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   token =  models.CharField(max_length=120, default=None, null= True)
   forgot_token = models.CharField(default=None, max_length=120, null=True),
   email =  models.EmailField(unique = True, max_length=254, verbose_name='email address')
   
#clinic
class Clinic(models.Model):
   register_user =  models.OneToOneField(Registered_user, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True,) 
   clnc_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_phone = models.BigIntegerField(null= True)
   clnc_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_Job_Title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_county = models.CharField(max_length=255)                                                          
   clnc_postcode = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_town_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   clnc_created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   clnc_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   published = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
```

**View.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from adminPanel.models import Registered_user
from adminPanel.models import Clinic

def create_clinic(request):
    """This function will handle the process of registering new clinic to the portal, where user can register with following attributes
        clinic_name, contact_name, Job_Title, address_line1, address_line2, county, postcode, town_city, clinic_email, clininc_phone
    Args:
        request: client to server request
    Returns:
        title: This will pass the title from backend to the html
    """
    title = 'Create Clinic'
    request_url = request.get_full_path()
    if request.method == "POST":
        domain_name=get_current_site(request).domain
        token=str(random.random()).split('.')[1]
        link=f'http://{domain_name}/resetpassword/{token}'
        clinic_name = request.POST.get('clinic_name')
        contact_name = request.POST.get('contact_name')
        Job_Title = request.POST.get('Job_Title')
        address_line1 = request.POST.get('address_line1')
        address_line2 = request.POST.get('address_line2')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        postcode = request.POST.get('postcode')
        town_city = request.POST.get('town_city')
        clinic_email = request.POST.get('clinic_email')
        clinic_phone = request.POST.get('clinic_number')            clinic_user_instances = Registered_user.objects.create(
                username = clinic_user_name,
                email = clinic_email,
                token = token,
                is_clinic=True
            )
            clinic_user_instances.save()
            
            clinic_instances = Clinic.objects.create(
                clnc_name = clinic_name,
                clnc_phone = clinic_phone,
                clnc_contact_name = contact_name,
                clnc_Job_Title = Job_Title,
                clnc_address_line1 = address_line1,
                clnc_address_line2 = address_line2,
                clnc_county = country,
                clnc_postcode = postcode,
                # clnc_town_city =town_city,
                # username = clinic_username,
                # email = clinic_email,
                # token = token,
                # is_clinic=True
                
            )
            clinic_instances.save
            messages.info(request, f'{clinic_name} added successfully Please check your mail to set password')
            
            subject = 'Reset password'
            email_template = get_template('email.html').render({'link': link})
            from_email = 'recordsdevelopment@gmail.com'
            message = EmailMessage(subject, email_template, from_email, [clinic_email])
            message.content_subtype='html'
            message.send()
            
        else:
            content = {
                'title': title, 
                'requesturl':request_url,
                'clinic_values':clinic_values,
                'error': error
            }
            return render(request, 'create_clinic.html', content)
    return render(request, 'create_clinic.html', {'title': title, 'requesturl':request_url})
```

**error**
null value in column "**register_user_id**" of relation "adminPanel_clinic" violates not-null constraint
get null value

Please help

I have tries one to one relation to join all the tables

Comment: This view is quite a big mess. You should redesign it because right now the way you deal with the validation is definitly not the good way.
Have a look to the Django Forms here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/forms/
Especially the Model Forms which is what you need.

Your perror message basically comes from the fact that your do not fill the register_user when you save your model, this field refuse null values so an error is raised. As well I think you are looking for one to many relationship not one to one if I understood well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating the Clinic instance, you need to pass `register_user` permeameter with `Registered_user` object like this:

```
       clinic_user_instances = Registered_user.objects.create(
            username = clinic_user_name,
            email = clinic_email,
            token = token,
            is_clinic=True
        )
        
        # No need to call additional save() method
        clinic_instances = Clinic.objects.create(
            clnc_name = clinic_name,
            clnc_phone = clinic_phone,
            clnc_contact_name = contact_name,
            clnc_Job_Title = Job_Title,
            clnc_address_line1 = address_line1,
            clnc_address_line2 = address_line2,
            clnc_county = country,
            clnc_postcode = postcode,
            register_user = clinic_user_instances 
        )
```

Comment: thanks Bro It works fine for me 
Can you please let me know should i use one to one relation or many to one relation

Comment: it depends on your usecases. if one user can have multiple clinics, then it should one to many, if one user can only have one clinic, then its one to one.

Comment: The super admin is creating all the clinic's and clinic can create multiple patient's, as per user suggestion I should use one to many relation in both situations